# Why can we use the energy of a pendulum to calculate its frequency?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

The question might sound rather vague; to calculate the frequency using the energy we simply use that the total energy is constant, set the derivative to zero and solve the equation of motion that follows. But my question is more about the why; how does the fact that the total energy is constant imply that we are able to calculate the frequency of the system? It seems to me as if this implies some sort of deeper connection, other than simply because the math allows us to, or the fact that both the frequency and the energy are constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using "can" in two different ways here, one as it is intended and one in the sense of "may".  We may use the energy being constant to calculate frequency because energy is conserved.  We are using that observed fact/postulate in our calculation.  We can use energy to calculate frequency because it works.  It is a productive way to solve the equation.